# Uniform convergence of real part of sequence of holomorphic functions implies uniform convergence of {$f_n$}

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

This question is part of an assignment which I am trying and I couldn't solve this particular question .

> Question:Let f , $f_n$ (n=1,2,3...) be holomorphic functions on a region $\Omega$ . If Re($f_n$) converges uniformly to Re(f)  then prove that $f_n$ converges uniformly to f.

I found this question :
[Uniform convergence of real part of holomorphic functions on compact sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296705/uniform-convergence-of-real-part-of-holomorphic-functions-on-compact-sets)

But it assumes 1 additional hypothesis .

So , can anyone please tell how can I prove this particular result.

thanks!!

Comment: you need to control $\Im f(w)$ for at least one $w$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional assumption in the link is absolutely necessary. Take $f_n(z)=in ,f(z)=0$ for a counter-example.